# Silent background app or service that sends current location to a server via post method (page php) and must enable the GPS button if deactivated

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, position, root

I would like to create a silent app that works in the background.

- must send the current position to a server via post method (to a php page).
- does not have to ask the user for permissions to enable and acquire the GPS position.
- must enable the GPS toggle if deactivated or if it is deactivated by the user.
- the smartphone is rooted.

---

fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);

I tried with part of this code, but this way I create a full-fledged app and I can't hide it, and it asks me for permission to use GPS.